# How to solve `not a valid enum value for `address.country` while adding the customer?

Tags: square

I'm integrating the square api's with golang in my software. But there is a problem while I'm sending the add customer request with the below json object

```
{
  "given_name": "Sand Box Customer",
  "family_name": "This is a sandbox Family",
  "email_address": "sandbox@gmail.com",
  "address": {
    "address_line_1": "500 Electric Ave",
    "address_line_2": "Suite 600",
    "locality": "New York",
    "administrative_district_level_1": "NY",
    "postal_code": "10003",
    "country": "Australia"
  },
  "phone_number": "1-212-555-4240",
  "reference_id": "YOUR_REFERENCE_ID",
  "note": "a customer"
}
```

and in response it returns me with an error:-

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
      "code": "INVALID_ENUM_VALUE",
      "detail": "`Australia` is not a valid enum value for `address.country`.",
      "field": "address.country"
    }
  ]
}
```

Why this error I'm facing while It will support the `Australia` country see in the link https://docs.connect.squareup.com/. How can I solve this error?

documentation link:- https://docs.connect.squareup.com/get-started

Comment: May you need to pass country code instead of countryname

Comment: @iambatman You are saying instead of  `Australia` I have to pass `AUS`? if yes, Then I have tried this too. and facing the same error.

Comment: Please share the exact documentation link which tells about the country intagration

Comment: Just pass `AU` and let me know the result

Comment: @iambatman yes now it will save the data what is exactly done there can you tell me?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their documentation, you should specify the country in `/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2` format.

Refer the doc

https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#type-location .

You can find more information from this also  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2